# Sql query issue with date

Tags: sql, database, date

I have a database as attached, in which i have a BirthDate column which is split into BirthYear, BirthMonth and BirthDayNumber.

[image: Database Image]

eg. For BirthDate:

```
Wednesday, May 10, 1899

BirthYear:1899
BirthMonth : 5
BirthDayNumber :10
```

I want to sort the database in the following format( the month and date should be in ascending order and in case if the month and date are equal then it should sort the year in descending order)

```
01 January 2011 
02 January 2012 
02 January 2008 
05 August 2012 
06 September 2001 
12 December 1899
```

Can you please help me out with the query for displaying the list in this format.

Comment: BirthMonth ASC, BirthDay ASC or OrderYear DESC this is what you want?

Comment: I am using sqlite as I have to then connect this to an iphone application. In BirthMonth ASC, BirthDay ASC or OrderYear DESC i  am getting it sorted by year. The year should be taken into consideration only if the month and date are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this works

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a12d1/1)

Using this code

```
SELECT birthdate FROM testdate 
ORDER BY 
BirthDayNumber ASC, BirthMonth ASC, BirthYear Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY BirthYear DESC, BirthDayNumber ASC, BirthMonth ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try query given below

```
SELECT * FROM `tblename`  order by BirthYear DESC, BirthMonth ASC,BirthDayNumber ASC
```

thanks

Comment: I have tried this but I have to consider the year only if the day and month are equal. I this case I am getting:


02 January 2012
05 August 2012 
01 January 2011 
02 January 2008 
06 September 2001 
12 December 1899 

But I require output like: 

01 January 2011 
02 January 2012 
02 January 2008 
05 August 2012 
06 September 2001 
12 December 1899

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DT ORDER BY YE DESC, MO ASC, DT ASC) AS NR, DT, MO, YE FROM SOMEDATA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(BirthDayNumber,' ', MonthName(CONCAT('1900-',CONVERT(BirthMonth,char(2)),'-1')), ' ', Birthyear)
FROM table
ORDER BY BirthMonth ASC, BirthDay ASC, BirthYear DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT birthdate FROM testdate 
ORDER BY 
BirthMonth  ASC,BirthDayNumber  ASC, BirthYear Desc
```